# Mockito , unable to initialize JNDI or anything which comes from servlet container

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, junit, mockito

i have to write test cases for few servlets in a JEE application , one simple call is making use of many beans and DataSource using  JNDI , problem is every time i mock a servelt , i get error on every place where servelt is calling anything which takes input from servlet container. for instance.

```
     //servelts calls getDataSource()   
    public static synchronized DataSource getDataSource() throws NamingException {
    return getDataSource(XYZConfig.DATA_SOURCE);
}

 public static synchronized DataSource getDataSource(String dataSourceName) throws NamingException {
    DataSource dataSource=null;
    InitialContext initCntx=null;
    try{

        //TODO: remove
        //hMap.remove(dataSourceName);
        if(hMap.get(dataSourceName) != null){
            dataSource=(DataSource) hMap.get(dataSourceName);
        }else{
            try{
                    initCntx=new InitialContext();
                    dataSource=(DataSource) initCntx.lookup(dataSourceName);
                if(dataSource!=null){
                    hMap.put(dataSourceName,dataSource);
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                dataSourceName = XYZConfig.DATA_SOURCE;
                if(hMap.get(dataSourceName) != null){
                    dataSource=(DataSource) hMap.get(dataSourceName);
                }else{
                    initCntx = new InitialContext();
                    dataSource=(DataSource) initCntx.lookup(FoursoftConfig.DATA_SOURCE);
                    if(dataSource!=null){
                        hMap.put(dataSourceName,dataSource);    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }finally{

    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

now i mocked the servlet , how can my servlet work when call is made from outside servelt container , NO JNDI is initialized , even if i do , i need to change code on source a little bit , i can't do that. and it's not just JNDI , same applies in few more bean.
All help is much appreciated. Thanks.

i am mocking servlet as

```
  HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
  HttpServletResponse   response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);  
  when(request.getParameter("username")).thenReturn("user1"); 
  when(request.getParameter("password")).thenReturn("pass1"); 
  new UnitServelt().doPost(request,response);
```

Exception is as follows :

Map controllerMap=(Map)getServletContext().getAttribute("controllerMap");

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletConfig has not been initialized
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:185)
at com.foursoft.etrans.common.servlets.ETransServlet.doPost(ETransServlet.java:56)
at   com.foursoft.etrans.unitcase.MockRequest.testDoPostHttpServletRequestHttpServletResponse(MockRequest.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

if i hard code controllerMap , then i get exception on following line

```
  initCntx=new InitialContext();
                    dataSource=(DataSource)    initCntx.lookup(dataSourceName);
```

as NoInitialContextException.

I know exactly what is happening , my test case are running from outside the container , obviously it can't have a servletContext and anything which comes from container , my Question is , what can i do , whole application is using HttpServletRequest everywhere , everywhere there is EJB and JNDI used , how can i provide that while running it outside of a container.

Comment: How did you mock the servlet?  How are you expecting your mock to get called?

Comment: it would be something like this..

     HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
     HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        when(request.getParameter("username")).thenReturn("user1");
        when(request.getParameter("password")).thenReturn("pass1");

        new UnitServelt().doPost(request,response);

Comment: So you're not mocking the servlet then, only HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse?

Comment: OK, next question - can you tell us what actually goes wrong?  Saying "i get error" doesn't really help.  What is the error, and is there a stack trace you can give us?

Comment: sorry about that , exception is , NoInitialContextException need to specify environment or system property .. something like that , i post complete stacktrace in sometime.

Comment: I updated the original post , Kindly check again. and thanks for you time David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer to this depends on whether you're trying to do an integration test of the entire servlet, all its interactions, and also the container itself; or whether you're trying to unit test just the servlet class.

To integration test the entire servlet in situ, you could start the container running in the development environment, and have a series of tests that actually make HTTP requests, and examine

- the HTTP responses;
- any other effects that the requests to the servlet should have, for example changes in a database.

It makes sense to use JUnit for this, but there is probably no need for Mockito.

On the other hand, if all you're doing is unit testing the servlet class, you should mock the ServletConfig and any other classes within the container's API that the servlet class actually uses.

Comment: Thanks David,i just got into this project,i am asked to integrate Junit to avoid manual testing,i never done any unit/integration testing,but i examined the complete code and it's business logic is very tightly coupled with servlet container,i never done unit testing but i know this for sure that it's very bad practice,tho they are trying for Junit integration but because of the limitation of application being so old and in my opinion badly coded, i am thinking of suggesting them for ServeltUnit/HttpUnit , it will atleast reduce some manual testing.
please share your thought on this please.

Comment: Well I've never used either ServletUnit or HttpUnit, so I can't comment on whether either would be appropriate for your situation.  But my experience is that retro-fitting tests of any type to legacy code that is already known to work isn't particularly cost effective.  Most of the value of unit testing comes if you test early, preferably either at the same time as the application code is written, or even earlier.  Some more of my thoughts on the economics of automated testing are at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10162116/1081110